# Php Designer, фокус при вводе переменной

Tags: php

Пытаюсь использовать PHP Designer, очень нравиться проверка синтаксиса налету, но есть "прикол" с программой, при написании когда после создания любой новой переменной

```
$some_var=
```

при вводе знака `=`, сразу теряется фокус со строки кода и перемещается на панель Code Explorer справа! Приходиться указателем опять перемещать фокус на нужную строку чтобы дописать код, очень-очень бесит! Думал, что это глюк, скачал версии программы с 7 - 8 во всех версиях одно и то же! Можно как-то отключить эту настройку?!

Comment: Как вариант, посмотрите, не зажимается ли у вас еще какая-то кнопка или проверьте назначения клавиш в программе. Работал долго с 7й и 8й, таких глюков не было.

Comment: ставь phpstorm

Comment: Поставил Phpstrom, все устраивает, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Отключи `TeamViewer`, и тогда фокус не будет теряться.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?